# How to return nodes between a node and the top of a tree in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to learn neo4j and was going to start with a basic employee / employer example where an employee has a manager unless at the top of the tree.

My structure looks like employee->MANAGEDBY->manager->MANAGEDBY->manager->MANAGEDBY->manager.  However each manger can have multiple employees or managers under them.

What I would like to be able to do is to get a list of all managers between an employee and main boss(ceo/president/whatever).

Initially I started off with a query like this

```
    MATCH(baseEmployee {Name: 'Josh'})-[:MANAGEDBY*0..]-(managers) 
    RETURN managers.Name;
```

This seems to not only show my manager and his/her manager and so on but it also seems to show everyone that they manage when what I want to show up is a list like

```
Josh,
Boss,
BossBoss,
BossBossBoss,
CEO
```

After some searching and some luck I managed to get closer by using the following query

```
MATCH p=(baseEmployee {Name: 'Josh'})-[:MANAGEDBY*0..]-(managers) 
WHERE NOT(managers-[:MANAGEDBY]->())
RETURN p;
```

I am just learning neo4j so my best guess of what is happening here is that I get the path from myself to the first manager who doesn't have a MANAGEDBY relationship.  My issue is that this returns a path and I would prefer to just have a list of managers.

Is it possible to do this without doing the p= query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the **direction of the relationship** to your path query!
Otherwise you also explore downwards from *Josh*.

And if you start your varlength query at zero `0..` then you return *Josh* too.
The default is `1..` so you can also leave it off.

You can return the nodes of the path with `nodes(p)`.

```
MATCH p=(baseEmployee {Name: 'Josh'})-[:MANAGEDBY*]->(managers) 
WHERE NOT(managers-[:MANAGEDBY]->())
RETURN nodes(p);
```

If you want to have one row per node you can do one of two:
Either unwind the collection back into rows.

```
MATCH p=(baseEmployee {Name: 'Josh'})-[:MANAGEDBY*]->(managers) 
WHERE NOT(managers-[:MANAGEDBY]->())
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
RETURN n;
```

Or return the last node of each path up to the root.

```
MATCH p=(baseEmployee {Name: 'Josh'})-[:MANAGEDBY*]->(managers) 
RETURN managers;
```

Comment: I did not know that you could specify the direction of the relationship.  I think something like MATCH(baseEmployee {Name: 'Josh'})-[:MANAGEDBY*0..]->(managers) 
RETURN managers.Name; fits my needs perfectly as it goes from me to the highest level of the tree and seems to only include the parents in the tree and never traverses downwards